# What is the difference between Eclipse's Content Assist and Context Information?

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse offers Content Assist (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) and Context Information (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>), what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> can be used to show parameter hints in a method call. Place the caret in the arguments list of a method call and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to see the parameter hints.

[image]